# jQuery validate Plugin add Code to forbid mail adresses without a dot

Tags: jquery, validation

I already tried different scripts I found on google but none worked for me. I have got this code

```js
jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
  required: "",
  email: "Bitte geben Sie eine gültige E-Mail Adresse ein.",
});


$(document).ready(function() {

  $('input').on('blur keyup', function() {
    if ($("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form").valid()) {
      $('#mc-embedded-subscribe').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
      $('#mc-embedded-subscribe').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  });

  $("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form").validate({
    rules: {
      email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      }
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="themailadressemanager.com" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
  <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
    <div class="mc-field-group">
      <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Jetzt Report anfordern" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button" disabled="disabled">
  </div>
</form>
```

to validate the mail adresses. But it does allow Mail adresses like a@b or .a@b
I do know that a@b can be a valid email adress, but is there an option to filter out a@b and .a@b email adresses aswell?

Comment: Please update the snippet with relevant HTML

Comment: <form action="themailadressemanager.com" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
<div class="mc-field-group">
         
 <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
</div>

       <input type="submit" value="Jetzt Report anfordern" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button" disabled="disabled">

Comment: The snippet. I did it for you...

Comment: Thanks! Anyone got an idea now?

Comment: read the duplicate, keep or change the regex